moment.tz not defiend on home page
I've tried to read everywhere and asked chatgpt but i cant find a solution.
i created this plugin here and its working fine via the following page https://nourhammoury.com/
However, on this home page, I get in the console the error moment.tz is not defined and the main js script (see bellow) doesn't execute.
Below is the code I am using. I hope i can find a solution
<?php

// Enqueue scripts and styles for the client-side
function nh_appointments_enqueue_client_scripts() {
    // Enqueue Stripe.js
    wp_enqueue_script('stripe', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/');

    // Enqueue FullCalendar CSS and JS
    wp_enqueue_style('fullcalendar-style', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css');

    // Check if moment.js is already loaded to avoid conflicts
    if (!wp_script_is('moment', 'enqueued')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('moment', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js', array('jquery'), '2.29.1', true);
    }

    // Check if moment-timezone is already loaded to avoid conflicts
    if (!wp_script_is('moment-timezone', 'enqueued')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('moment-timezone', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.34/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js', array('moment'), '0.5.34', true);
    }

    wp_enqueue_script('fullcalendar', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js', array('jquery', 'moment', 'moment-timezone'), '3.10.2', true);

    // Enqueue custom CSS
    wp_enqueue_style('nh-appointments-style', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '../css/style.css');

    // Check if the site is being viewed in Arabic and enqueue the Arabic CSS file
    if (defined('ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE') && ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'ar') {
        wp_enqueue_style('nh-arabic-style', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '../css/style-ar.css');
    }

    // Localize and enqueue custom JS
    wp_enqueue_script('nh-appointments-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '../js/script.js', array('jquery', 'fullcalendar', 'moment-timezone'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('nh-appointments-script', 'nhAppointments', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'slotAlreadyBooked' => __('This slot is already booked. Please choose another time.', 'nh-appointments'),
        'slotAvailable' => __('Available', 'nh-appointments'),
        'slotBooked' => __('Booked', 'nh-appointments'),
        'slotNotAvailable' => __('This slot is not available. Please choose another time.', 'nh-appointments'),
        'bookingSuccessful' => __('Booking Successful!', 'nh-appointments'),
        'appointmentConfirmed' => __('Your appointment is confirmed.', 'nh-appointments'),
        'nameLabel' => __('Name:', 'nh-appointments'),
        'phoneLabel' => __('Phone:', 'nh-appointments'),
        'dateLabel' => __('Date:', 'nh-appointments'),
        'timeLabel' => __('Time:', 'nh-appointments'),
        'timezoneLabel' => __('Timezone:', 'nh-appointments')
    ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'nh_appointments_enqueue_client_scripts');

// Enqueue scripts and styles for the admin-side
function nh_appointments_enqueue_admin_scripts($hook) {
    if ($hook != 'toplevel_page_nh_appointments') {
        return;
    }

    // Enqueue FullCalendar CSS and JS
    wp_enqueue_style('fullcalendar-style', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css');

    // Check if moment.js is already loaded to avoid conflicts
    if (!wp_script_is('moment', 'enqueued')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('moment', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js', array('jquery'), '2.29.1', true);
    }

    // Check if moment-timezone is already loaded to avoid conflicts
    if (!wp_script_is('moment-timezone', 'enqueued')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('moment-timezone', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.34/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js', array('moment'), '0.5.34', true);
    }

    wp_enqueue_script('fullcalendar', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js', array('jquery', 'moment', 'moment-timezone'), '3.10.2', true);

    // Enqueue custom admin CSS and JS
    wp_enqueue_style('nh-appointments-admin-style', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '../css/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('nh-admin-calendar', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '../js/admin-calendar.js', array('jquery', 'fullcalendar', 'moment-timezone'), null, true);

    // Localize the script with new data
    wp_localize_script('nh-admin-calendar', 'nh_appointments_ajax', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    ));

    // Enqueue slot management script
    wp_enqueue_script('nh-slots-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '../js/slots.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('nh-slots-script', 'nh_appointments_slots_ajax', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    ));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'nh_appointments_enqueue_admin_scripts');
?>

and this is my script.js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Ensure nhAppointments and moment.tz are defined before using them
    if (typeof nhAppointments === 'undefined') {
        console.error('nhAppointments is not defined');
        return;
    }

    if (typeof moment.tz === 'undefined') {
        console.error('moment.tz is not defined');
        return;
    }

    var stripe = Stripe('*****');
    var elements = stripe.elements();
    
    var style = {
        base: {
            color: '#32325d',
            fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#aab7c4'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
        }
    };
    
    var card = elements.create('card', { style: style });
    card.mount('#card-element');

    var availableDates = {};
    var bookedSlots = {};

    // Initialize FullCalendar
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: nhAppointments.ajax_url,
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'nh_get_client_slots',
                    start_date: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    end_date: end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    var events = [];
                    availableDates = {}; // Clear previous data
                    bookedSlots = {}; // Clear previous data
                    if (response.success) {
                        // Process booked slots
                        $.each(response.data.booked_slots, function(index, slot) {
                            var originalDateTime = slot.date + ' ' + slot.time + ' ' + slot.timezone;
                            var selectedTimezone = moment.tz.guess();
                            var convertedDateTime = moment.utc(slot.date + 'T' + slot.time).tz(selectedTimezone).format();
                            bookedSlots[convertedDateTime] = true;
                            events.push({
                                title: nhAppointments.slotBooked,
                                start: convertedDateTime,
                                allDay: false,
                                color: 'red',  // Custom color for booked slots
                                editable: false
                            });
                        });

                        // Process available slots
                        $.each(response.data.available_slots, function(index, slot) {
                            var originalDateTime = slot.date + ' ' + slot.time + ' ' + slot.timezone;
                            var convertedDateTime = moment.utc(slot.date + 'T' + slot.time).tz(moment.tz.guess()).format();
                            availableDates[convertedDateTime] = true;
                            if (!bookedSlots[convertedDateTime]) {
                                events.push({
                                    title: nhAppointments.slotAvailable,
                                    start: convertedDateTime,
                                    allDay: false,
                                    color: 'blue'  // Custom color for available slots
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    callback(events);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    console.error('Error fetching slots:', error);  // You may want to keep this for catching AJAX errors
                }
            });
        },
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {
            var selectedDate = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var selectedTime = start.format('HH:mm');
            var selectedTimezone = moment.tz.guess();
            var dateTime = selectedDate + 'T' + selectedTime + ':00';

            if (!bookedSlots[dateTime] && availableDates[dateTime]) {
                $('#appointment-date').val(selectedDate);
                $('#appointment-time').val(selectedTime);
                $('#appointment-timezone').val(selectedTimezone);

                $('#nh-booking-form').show();
                $('#calendar').hide();
            } else {
                alert(nhAppointments.slotNotAvailable);
            }
        },
        dayRender: function(date, cell) {
            var dateStr = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            if (!availableDates[dateStr]) {
                cell.addClass('fc-disabled');
                cell.css('background-color', '#f4f4f4');
                cell.css('cursor', 'default');
            }
        },
        eventClick: function(event) {
            var selectedDate = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            var selectedTime = event.start.format('HH:mm');
            var selectedTimezone = moment.tz.guess();
            var dateTime = selectedDate + 'T' + selectedTime + ':00';

            if (event.title === nhAppointments.slotAvailable) {            
                $('#appointment-date').val(selectedDate);
                $('#appointment-time').val(selectedTime);
                $('#appointment-timezone').val(selectedTimezone);

                $('#nh-booking-form').show();
                $('#calendar').hide();
            } else {
                alert(nhAppointments.slotAlreadyBooked);
            }
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            if (event.color) {
                element.css('background-color', event.color);
                element.css('border-color', event.color);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#nh-booking-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        stripe.createPaymentMethod('card', card).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
                alert(result.error.message);
            } else {
                var formData = $('#nh-booking-form').serialize();
                formData += '&payment_method_id=' + result.paymentMethod.id;

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: nhAppointments.ajax_url,
                    data: {
                        action: 'nh_handle_booking',
                        data: formData
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            // Convert the UTC time to the user's local time
                            var utcDateTime = moment.utc(response.data.date + 'T' + response.data.time);
                            var localDateTime = utcDateTime.local();
                            var localDate = localDateTime.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                            var localTime = localDateTime.format('HH:mm');
                            var localTimezone = moment.tz.guess(); // Get the user's local timezone

                            $('#nh-booking-form').hide();
                            $('#confirmation-message').html('<h2>' + nhAppointments.bookingSuccessful + '</h2>' +
                                '<p>' + nhAppointments.appointmentConfirmed + '</p>' +
                                '<p><strong>' + nhAppointments.nameLabel + '</strong> ' + response.data.name + '</p>' +
                                '<p><strong>' + nhAppointments.phoneLabel + '</strong> ' + response.data.phone + '</p>' +
                                '<p><strong>' + nhAppointments.dateLabel + '</strong> ' + localDate + '</p>' +
                                '<p><strong>' + nhAppointments.timeLabel + '</strong> ' + localTime + ' (' + localTimezone + ')</p>');

                            // Refetch events to update the calendar
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        } else {
                            alert('Error: ' + response.data.message);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert('AJAX error: ' + error);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

I tried everything i can, including ChatGPT and Gemini AI

On https://nourhammoury.com the problem appears, in the generated code the script with src to moment.min.js has attribute defer. However, on https://nourhammoury.com/make-an-appointment/ there's no problem, the same script (moment.min.js) doesn't have the attribute defer. Can you trace the difference between the two in php? For the defer attribute to be added, the call to wp_enqueue_script should typically add a defer loading strategy (as the last argument, $args) see the docs at defer.

checked network i found the following on the main page
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js?ver=2.29.1
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.34/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js?ver=0.5.34
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js?ver=6.5.5
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js?ver=6.5.5
